# How to render hyperlink as grid data in Data grid In ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Data Grid similar to this :

Main.js

```
<DataGrid>
headerHeight={35}
headerWidth={50}
onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
columnDefs={gridColumnDef}
rowData={gridData}
{...this.props}/>
```

**and I have function that sets the grid data in Main.js**

```
initializeGridData(data){
let obj;
for(let i =0;i<data.length;i++)
{
obj=data[i];
for(let k=0;k<obj.length;k++){
completeData.push(
{
id:obj[k].id
link:obj[k].link
})
}
}
gridData= completeData;
}
}


**I have a JS file that defines the column (gridColumnDef.js)**

export const gridColumnDef=[
{
headerName:
field:id
},
{
headerName:
field:link
},
];
```

Here I want to render the link field as an hyperlink . Can anyone suggest how to do it .
Thanks

Comment: I tried fixing the codeblock formatting, but discovered that there appears to be syntax errors in the first and second example (extra `>` in the first and extra closing bracket `}` in the second).  Also, is `DataGrid` your own component, or does it belong to an existing library?  If the latter, you might want to include a link, or a tag if one exists.

Comment: I have rolled this question back to its initial form.  There were a lot of well-meaning edits, but [at least one of them _functionally changed the code_](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59502130/3) by converting the function **definition** of `initializeGridData` into a function **call**.  @Ramya, please review the code blocks in this question and fix the formatting and resolve any syntax issues that may be distracting from the core issue of your question.  You can get tips on formatting [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).